# How to extract column wise data from pdf in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to read a .pdf file which has some data. How can I extract complete data from one specific column only using powershell? I am using iText 5 .NET (aka iTextSharp) for pdf data extraction.

This is my current code, which extracts an entire line:

```
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList testPOC.pdf
$page = 2
$text = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page).Split([char]0x000A)
Write-Host $text[5]
```

Output is shown as:

```
ID          Working Agent   Assistant Name        Plan           Gender  Year   Amount     Comm.%  Split%   Commission
4169985061  Paul E. Ted     Alskd, Ols      fhghslhshsl+(0sdhsk)    M      12   $1,234.00   0.45%   100.00%  $32.78
```

How can I get data only from one single column (eg. only from salary column)?

Comment: The simplest approach would be to split each line at spaces and select the relevant field: `$line.Split(' ')[4]`. For further help you need to provide a representative sample of the text you extracted from the PDF.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I tried that approach but the problem is I cannot predict about the length and pattern of name column.It might contain first,middle and last name or it might contain only first and last name.Same problem arises on other columns too.

Comment: I suspected as much. That's why I said you need to provide a representative sample of the text you extracted from the PDF. We can't devise a way to parse data from text without knowing the structure of the text.

Comment: Does iTextSharp have a method for rendering the result in CSV format?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a blind stab at the answer, because we don't know what type of data $text is (unless we are iTextSharp experts).  You could find that out for us by entering:

```
$text.gettype()
```

From the way it shows up on output, it almost appears that it's a PSCustomObject.  If so, an approach like this might work:

```
$text | select-object ID, Commission
```

I used Commission because I couldn't see Salary in your output.  I added ID for the sake of context.

Note:  a real answer is going to have to wait for somebody who uses iTextSharp and might know the datatype of $text without being told.  That could be a long wait.

Comment: data type of $text is String in my case

Comment: Does the .Split break it into an array of strings?

Comment: Yes , it breaks the whole bunch of text on basis of new line.So that the text appear line by line

Comment: And there are only two lines in the output you have shown us.  Is that all there is, or did you just cut it to two lines before posting it in your question?

Comment: I have cut it down to just two because rest of the rows also contains values in similar fashion.

Comment: Is there a TAB character between fields?  I'm trying to be helpful, even if it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: The text I extracted only contains single whitespace and not any TAB character even though in pdf it is shownig that columns are separated by some space which more than a single whitespace.